# Mysql query-cache not working with mysql RDS read replication

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

`query_cache` is working fine in Master
But in RDS Read replica all things is enabled but not working so `qcache_hits` is zero.

Master is running with 4 cpu and 16GB ram , Slave with 2 CPU with 8 GB Ram

```
Variables-------Master-----Slave

query_alloc_block_size|8192|8192

query_cache_limit|1048576|1048576

query_cache_min_res_unit|4096|4096

query_cache_size|65536|32768

query_cache_type|ON|ON

query_cache_wlock_invalidate|OFF|OFF

query_prealloc_size|8192|8192

range_alloc_block_size|4096|4096

read_buffer_size|2097152|2097152


Status--------Master-----Slave

Qcache_free_blocks|3|0

Qcache_free_memory|8736|0

Qcache_hits|192258|0

Qcache_inserts|375703|0

Qcache_lowmem_prunes|366618|0

Qcache_not_cached|78314|0

Qcache_queries_in_cache|19|0

Qcache_total_blocks|52|0

Queries|1226261|316005
```

I made a copy using aurora db and caching is working with Replica.

Please help read replicas are taking too much time to fetch data.

Comment: which version you are using ? **SELECT VERSION();**

Comment: Mysql version 5.5.46

Comment: `Qcache_total_blocks` can't be 0 if the query cache is actually enabled.  An empty query cache would have at least 1 (contiguous) block.  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%Q%CACHE%';`

Comment: Hi Michael,
I found that in RDS we need to define atleast 64 kb to enable working of Query cache , I thought that this value is in KB but it work in bytes so when it was set to 32 kb its not working when i increased it to 64 kb it start working , I found in Mysql that need to define atleast 1 mb. Thanks for all help & time

Answer (score 0):

I thought that this value is in KB but it work in bytes so when it was set to 32 kb its not working when i increased it to 64 kb it start working , I found in Mysql that need to define at-least 1 mb to work but in my case 64536 also worked.

Thanks for all help and time.